# Array and using pointer in C

Tags: c

I'm new to c programming and using pointers , I would like to write a function  using a pointer that points to one array and manipulate array items so that low previous item equals the above next item in array.
Here is the original code that I want to use pointers on:

```
G = 60;
size = 60;
double Array[60 * 60]; 

for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  if (i % G != 0) {
    for (m = 0; m < size; m++) {
      Array[m * G + i] = Array[((m * G) + i - 1)];
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make the previous code using a function that take int pointer and return final Array values ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not quite certain what you want to achieve. Can you (a) format your code better and (b) add code that depicts the usage of this function in your mind?

Answer (score 1):

```
void func(double* arr, size_t number_of_elements) {
    //Initialize local variables i, G, m, ...
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(i%G!=0){
            for(m=0;m<size;m++){
                Array[m*G +i] = Array[((m*G) +i-1)];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
func(array, sizeof(Array)/sizeof(Array[0]));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but i will make my question clear as possible.
my code includes  function that returns a pointer to array . i want here in my question to make another function that take this pointer of array as argument and then manipulate in this form: Array[m*G +i] = Array[((m*G) +i-1)] and finally returns the new array ..

Comment: Here is my code :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int i ,m,j;
int G=60;
int counter=1;
int source=1;
int inf = 2147483647;
Double * Lenght;
double * setLenght(){
static double L[60*60];
counter=1;
for(i=0;i<G;i++){
if(i%G == 0){
if(counter ==source){
for(j=i;j<i+G;j++){
L[j]=0;}}
 else{
 L[j]=inf;}
counter++;}
}return L;}
double * updateLenght (double * lenghtarr){
static double Larray[60*60];
for (i=1;i<G;i++){
if(i%G !=0){
for(m=0;m<G;m++){
Larray[m*G +i]=  *(lenghtarr+(m*G) +i-1);
}}}return Larray;}
int main() { Lenght=setLenght();
updateLenght(Lenght);}